# How do I monitor transactions in a Polygon wallet?

Tags: cryptography, cryptocurrency

So I'm wanting to monitor a Polygon wallet for when transactions occur. It doesn't seem like there are a ton of resources for Polygon wallet monitoring, mostly just for Bitcoin and Ethereum wallet monitoring. What's the process to develop a program to monitor a Polygon wallet? Is there an API I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use web3 js, to monitor all incoming transactions, and be iterating through them and comparing them with the list of your wallets.

I'm building a tool that will do all the checking for you, what tou just have to do is to just be uploading addresses that you want to watch for their incoming transactions.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! I would love to check out your tool once you've built it out.

Comment: I just made it available on GitHub few hours ago, you can check it now.  https://github.com/ahmadbrainworks/fiddi

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cryptocurrency Alerting's [Polygon wallet monitoring](https://cryptocurrencyalerting.com/wallet-watch.html?blockchain=MATIC) service.  They have an API where you can manage alert conditions and you can receive notifications via a webhook JSON payload.